# React Native : Progress bars animation not filling from left to right but from center to sides

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make an upper progress bars similar to instagram stories progress bars, while i got to animate it's not animating the way I want.

The bars should fill from left to right, sadly the bars are filling from the center to the sides...

Some things to takein note, bars width is variable, also I'm thinking about maybe using translateX instead of scaleX.

My react native code:

```
 const milliseconds = 10000;

    // Create an array of Animated.Values for each item's progress bar (scaleX)
const scaleAnims = items.map(() => useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current);

useEffect(() => {
    startProgressBar(activeIndex);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % items.length;
        setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
        startProgressBar(nextIndex);
    }, milliseconds);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [items.length, activeIndex]);


    

    const startProgressBar = (index) => {
      // Reset the progress bar for the active index
      scaleAnims[index].setValue(0);
  
      // Start the animation
      Animated.timing(scaleAnims[index], {
          toValue: 1, // Scale to full width
          duration: milliseconds,
          useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
  };


<View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5, height: 8, zIndex: 999, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', position: 'absolute', top: 70, left: 0,  width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            {items.map((bar, index) => (
                <View key={index} style={{ height: 8, paddingVertical: 2, zIndex: 999, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden', flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 5, borderRadius: 20, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <Animated.View style={{
                        height: '100%',
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        transform: [{ scaleX: scaleAnims[index] }],
                        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                        width: '100%', // Initial width set to a small value,
                        position:'absolute',top:0,left:0
                    }} />
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
```